# Disk Quota Warning timer Job in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, timer-jobs, notifications

The below Microsoft article talks about Disk Quota Warning Time job in SharePoint Online.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits

But SharePoint Online admin center doesn't have any timer jobs section.

How to configure the schedule for Disk Quota Warning timer job in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

Timer jobs cannot be configured in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Then how are the site quota notifications are triggered for SPO?

Comment: Timer jobs (most likely) that you don't have access to. This isn't on-prem -- you have no access to the underlying farms.